# SocketIO Chrome Inspector Frames

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I was playing around with Socket.IO and ran into some questions when viewing the frames in the chrome inspector.

[image]

What do the numbers beside each frame's content mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's the Engine.io protocol where the number you see is the packet encoding:

```
<packet type id>[<data>]
```

example:

```
2probe
```

And these are the different packet types:

**0 open**

Sent from the server when a new transport is opened (recheck)

**1 close**

Request the close of this transport but does not shutdown the connection itself.

**2 ping**

Sent by the client. Server should answer with a pong packet containing the same data

example 1. client sends: 2probe 2. server sends: 3probe

**3 pong**

Sent by the server to respond to ping packets.

**4 message**

actual message, client and server should call their callbacks with the data.

example 1

server sends: 4HelloWorld
client receives and calls callback `socket.on('message', function (data) { console.log(data); });`

example 2

client sends: 4HelloWorld
server receives and calls callback `socket.on('message', function (data) { console.log(data); });`

**5 upgrade**

Before engine.io switches a transport, it tests, if server and client can communicate over this transport. If this test succeed, the client sends an upgrade packets which requests the server to flush its cache on the old transport and switch to the new transport.

**6 noop**

A noop packet. Used primarily to force a poll cycle when an incoming websocket connection is received.

example

client connects through new transport
client sends 2probe
server receives and sends 3probe
client receives and sends 5
server flushes and closes old transport and switches to new.

You can read the full documentation [here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks @Fabio