# How socket.io disconnect works?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Socket.IO timeout (disconnect) occurs if there are no activity present in the socket, but how is detected that are no activity? I dont find information about that. How works the detection process? For example: 
If user closes the website tab, occurs disconnect?
There is any way user loses connection and disconnect will not be executed?
Is possible cache information informs that Im online even if I leave the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your browser's developer tools in the network panel, you can filter your requests to **ws** requests (web socket requests), in there you can see your active web sockets connections. If you choose one connection, you can see the headers, the frames, the cookies and timing. If you choose the frames option you can see what's being sent and received, between your browser and your web socket server.

The next image will make it clear for you, it's chrome's developer tools:

[image: Chrome developer tools]

Now in there you can see there are some numbers, basically your browser and your server are doing ping pong. You can read more about these numbers in this answer [SocketIO Chrome Inspector Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031347/socketio-chrome-inspector-frames/36032667#36032667)

This ping pong is what keeps the socket alive so we know that there are no timeouts. As for the disconnect and the connect I advise you to read more about the [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), in there you can see there are event listeners for onclose, onerror, onmessage and onopen.

So answering this question:

> For example: If user closes the website tab, occurs disconnect? There
>   is any way user loses connection and disconnect will not be executed?

No, the onclose event will be fired, but even if any cosmic reason the onclose isn't fired you will eventually disconnect due to timeout.

As for your other question:

> Is possible cache information informs that Im online even if I leave
>   the website?

Yes, that's not up to sockets, that's up to you and your implementation. You can keep a list of online users and only update that list from time to time, let's say 10 minutes. You can keep the online users lists and between the time you update your online users list, some of them are already disconnected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, helped my doubts.